# Exclude Timestamp time zone in the display, Rails application

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

Application.rb :

```
config.time_zone ='Eastern Time (US & Canada)'
```

Database entry : 
on the MySQL database : 2014-06-15 07:44:24.000

On the application interface when I display I get this :

```
on the application : 2014-06-15 03:44:24 -0400
```

But I want to display the exact date and time displayed as is, that is on the database like :

```
2014-06-15 07:44:24.000
```

Could some one help me out.Thanks!

Comment: Use the 'I18n' helpers to format date times, here is a blog post I did on ROR and timezones: http://jessehouse.com/blog/2013/11/15/working-with-timezones-and-ruby-on-rails/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to display timestamp in UTC format (the same as in your database), then simply convert time like this:

```
my_timestamp.utc
```

Comment: I am getting the right time. But there is a 'UTC' text coming attached along with this : 2014-06-15 07:44:24 UTC

Comment: you can fomat it, e.g. my_timestamp.utc.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.000")

Comment: or you can simply display it without UTC string with this: my_timestamp.utc.to_s(:db)